# Nifi - Remote Process Group - PeerSelector

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-nifi, peer, remote-process

I have build a simple Process Group. It generates a FlowFile with some random stuff in it and sends it to the Nifi Remote Process Group.
This Remote Process Group is configured to send the FlowFile to localhost or in this case to my own Hostname (I have tried localhost as well).

After this the FlowFile should Appear at the "From MiNiFi" input Port and is sended to the LogAttribute. Nothing Special.

[image: Here a screenshot of the Process Group]

I configured to using RAW but with HTTP it neither works.

I am using the apache/nifi docker image and didn´t changed something in nifi.properties and authorizers.xml but of couse i provide you both:

[nifi.properties](https://pastebin.com/Ca7nG0jz)

[authorizers.xml](https://pastebin.com/iigXdPCE)

The Error occuring is this:

```
WARNING org.apache.nifi.remote.client.PeerSelector@40081613 Unable to refresh Remote Group´s peers due to Unable to communicate with remote Nifi cluster in order to determine which nodes exist in the remote cluster
```

I hope you can help me. I have wasted too much time with this Problem XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nifi.properties you have nifi.web.http.host=f4f40c87b65f so that means the hostname that NiFi is listening for requests on is f4f40c87b65f which means the URL of your RPG must be http://f4f40c87b65f:8080/nifi

Comment: my nifi is running in a Docker container.I think f4f40c87b65f is the Docker Container ID.

Comment: If thats the case then your nifi.web.http.host value is wrong and needs to be the hostname

Comment: Thanks that helped me to figure out the connection issues

Comment: But how come I can access NiFi in browser using localhost, but cluster needs to have the container URL ?